# Could anyone tell me what verse is being recited in the video?

Tags: rig-veda, identification-request

In Ramanada Sagar's adaptation of the ***Ramayana*** whenever some yajna is performed, I can hear background recital of some verses which is repeated again and again. In the below video, at ~18:10 mins Vishwamitra is interuppted by Marich and Subahu when the former starts a yajna here once can hear the verse in chorus.

> [image]

I listen it unintelligibly as:

Vedaputra/Devaputra samvato vrikshnatma yajaamaha Indraya vischtai ?????? Indraya putri?? sandwawa?

Could any tell me from which book and what verse is being recited here

Comment: Looks like indra mantra if you can posts words we may try to find out

Comment: @RakeshJoshi had I known the words I would have searched by myself

Comment: Somehow audio was not that clear and not sure which words this mantra used. Something related to "Indra" but not sure .